# How can I avoid newlines after array elements when using readarray?

Tags: arrays, bash

I've got a text file

```
Today, 12:34 
Today, 21:43 
Today, 12:43
https://123
https://456
https://789
```

and wanted to print each line into an array. Therefore I used:

```
readarray array <'file.txt'
```

Now I'd like to create a new array mixing date and the corresponding link, so in this case, line 1 corresponds with line 4 and so on.
I wrote

```
declare -a array2
array2[0]=${array[0]}${array[3]}
array2[1]=${array[1]}${array[4]}
...
```

printing the whole array2 using "echo ${array2[*]}" gets the following:

```
Today, 12:34
https://123
 Today, 21:43
https://456
 Today, 12:43
https://789
```

Why are there newlines between the elements, so e.g. between array2[0] and array2[1] ? How could I get rid of them?
And why is there an empty space before T in the second and the following lines?
And is there a possibility to write the code above in a loop?

Kind regards,
X3nion

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-t` argument to prevent the newlines from being included in the data stored in the individual array elements:

```
readarray -t array <file.txt
```

BTW, you can always strip your newlines after-the-fact, even if you *don't* prevent them from being read in the first place, by using the `${var%suffix}` parameter expansion with the `$'\n'` syntax to refer to a newline literal:

```
array2[0]=${array[0]%$'\n'}${array[3]%$'\n'}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution would be much simpler (and much faster). Simply read all lines containing `"Today"` into an array in `awk`. Then beginning with the line not containing `"Today"` write the current line followed by the associated line from the array, e.g.

```
awk '/Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, a[++m]}' file.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example lines in `file.txt`, you would receive:

```
$ awk '/Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, a[++m]}' file.txt
https://123     Today, 12:34
https://456     Today, 21:43
https://789     Today, 12:43
```

Or if you wanted to change the order:

```
$ awk '/Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s\t%s\n", a[++m], $0}' file.txt
Today, 12:34    https://123
Today, 21:43    https://456
Today, 12:43    https://789
```

**Addition Per-Comment**

If you are receiving whitespace before the output with `awk` that is due to having whitespace before the first field. To eliminate the whitespace, you can force `awk` to recalculate each field, removing whitespace simply by setting a field equal to itself, e.g.

```
awk '{$1 = $1} /Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s\t%s\n", a[++m], $0}' file.txt
```

By setting the first field equal to itself (`$1 = $1`), you force `awk` to recalculate each field which would eliminate leading whitespace. Take for example your data with leading whitespace (each line is preceded by 3-spaces):

```
   Today, 12:34
   Today, 21:43
   Today, 12:43
   https://123
   https://456
   https://789
```

Using the updated command gives the answers shown above with the whitespace removed.

**Using `paste`**

You can use the `paste` command as another option along with the `wc -l` (word count lines) command. Simply determined the number of lines and then use process substitution to output the first 1/2 of the lines followed by the last 1/2 of the lines and combine them with `paste`, e.g.

```
$ lc=$(wc -l <file.txt); paste <(head -n $((lc/2)) file.txt) <(tail -n $((lc/2)) file.txt)
Today, 12:34    https://123
Today, 21:43    https://456
Today, 12:43    https://789
```

(above, `lc` holds the line-count and then `head` and `tail` are used to split the file)
Let me know if you have questions or if this isn't what you were attempting to do.

Comment: @DavidCRankin The printf command unfortunately doesn't work out, I get the same output like above, but with some space between the left border and the text. But the paste command works! How can the space between the first column and the second column be reduced to 0, 1, ...? And how can I redirect the output of lc to the same text file?

Comment: See updated answer. Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: I still have got the whitespace between time and https. Besides that, I found out that the paste command is better, as the day differs (Today, Yesterday, ..). How would I get rid of whitespace between time and https using the paste command?

Comment: You can use `paste -d ' '` to use a single space as the delimiter.

Comment: Okay and paste -d '' to have no whitespace at all. How can I save the output of the command to the same file?

Comment: No. You have to use a temp file, e.g. `command < file > temp; mv -f temp file` will use a temp file and then replace the original with the temporary using `mv`. Depending on the actual format of your `file.txt` there are always more that can be done to tailor the format to just what you need. I still like the `awk '{$1 = $1} /Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s %s\n", a[++m], $0}'` command. `awk` gives you complete control over the resulting formatting. There are many different ways you can tweak the output.

Comment: Well yeah I believe you that the awk command would be better. But how would the command with the temp file in this case concretely look like?

Comment: When you say the `printf` doesn't work -- does your `file.txt` have DOS line-endings by chance? If it does, you can use `awk -v RS='\r\n' '{$1 = $1} /Today/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s %s\n", a[++m], $0}' ` You can check the line-endings with `head -n 1 file.txt | hexdump -Cv` and if you see `0d 0a` as the line ending -- you have DOS line ends. You can convert the file to unix with `dos2unix file.txt` or use the records separator shown above.

Comment: The printf command worked, but only in cases that the first lines start with "Today". But what can I do for other cases, i.e. "Yesterday, 12:34", or the last case where there only is only the date in "hhhh-mm-dd" without a time? Wouldn't it be better to use the paste command because of the different cases?

Comment: You can do it many different ways like `awk -v RS='\r\n' '{$1 = $1} ! /http/{a[++n] = $0; next} {printf "%s %s\n", a[++m], $0}'` which will consider everything that doesn't have `http` to be the date line